# Accessing app.settings when running NUnit

Tags: testing, nunit

My test fails. It made me sad. So I started debug on it and found out that the *NullReferenceException* occurs du to the line below.

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("blopp")
```

It doesn't happen when I actually run the program being tested (although the said call is not directly in the program but in one of its libraries).

Is that a bad design of the code or should I consider a different approach to the testing? Perhaps there's a way to fake-in the missing config line? I'm totally indecisive...

Comment: Are you testing the library that makes the GetSection call? Does that library have an app.config file containing that section?

Comment: @mattyB Yes. And yes. But there are a lot of weird dependencies so I fear that this will lead me nowhere...   :)

Comment: Are you using NUnit.exe? Sometimes if you're running your tests as part of a NUnit project there are problems with the app.config file being read correctly. If this is what you're doing now, try opening the test library directly instead.

Comment: Thanks. Please elaborate "*opening the test library directly*". Preferably as a part of a reply that can be accepted as an answer, if helpful.   :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had problems before using the NUnit GUI (nunit.exe) where when running tests as part of a NUnit project the app.config file is not read.

Try opening the test library directly in the NUnit GUI by clicking *File > Open project...* and then selecting the test library.